# Replacing a php file with a Vaadin view in Java

Tags: java, vaadin

I have been working with Vaadin for a bit, I am wondering if it is possible to substitute a php file with a Vaadin view.

So in Java, I normally go to a PHP-page to retrieve a file from my server. An indirect download, I guess. In my java project, I have the following code:

```
URL url = new URL("fileinphp.php");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setConnectTimeout(3000);
            conn.connect();
```

The php-page that sends the image is as such:

```
$file_name = $_GET['file'];
$file_url = '/files/' . $file_name;
header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
    header('Content-Type: ' . mime_content_type($file_url));
    header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$file_name."\"");
    readfile($file_url);
```

Now. I want to try to do the same in Vaadin. So I have tried to make the following page, and connect to it through the url-method above.

```
@Route("myroute")
public class Test extends Div {

public Test() {
    add(new Label("Does this get through?"));
}
}
```

All of this combined, provides me with the following body:

```
To test your app with this browser, enable transpilation in development mode.</p><p>Transpilation can be enabled by setting the <code>vaadin.devmode.transpile=true</code> property for the deployment configuration using an application or a system property.<p><p>Note that transpilation is always enabled for the <code>build-frontend</code> Maven goal, which is also used when creating a production build of the application.
```

Comment: Ignoring, that the error there states a different problem, which is totally agnostic what you are asking: what exaclty are you planning? You have a PHP applications somewhere, you query with another java application.  Now you want to replace the PHP application with a vaadin application to generate an image for the java application?

Comment: Basically, I had a php file that would serve me information in-directly. However, since then, I have manipulated the information (encrypted it) in a way that does not allow for it to be served through PHP. So I thought perhaps an alternate "route" could be to utilize Vaadin. So yeah, replace the php application (single page, basically just an echo function hidden behind some if-checks) with a vaadin page. And then, yes, allow for any java-application (android or plain java) to retrieve the info provided by the vaadin page.